# Linux command to send binary file to serial port with HW flow control?

Tags: linux, command-line, serial-port, command, flow-control

I need to send binary file *to rs232 device* (printer) which not always can accept data and so it has BUSY output signal, which i connect to CTS pin.

I try to use it with `minicom`, and hardware flow control works just fine. But i can't send raw file using minicom, it works wrong ant i think minicom not loves zeroes in file.

At other hand, i try to use `cat file > /dev/ttyS5`, along with `stty -F /dev/ttyS5 clocal` or `stty -F /dev/ttyS5 crtscts`. None of this work: HW control not work at all, data transfer just stops (often at middle of byte when **space** state on TXD stucks!) and never continues after release of BUSY. Behavior not depends on `clocal` or `crtscts` i use.
And also `cat file > /dev/ttyS5` never wait, even if BUSY was active *before* this command.

Please note, using minicom, i ensure that i have correct connections, support for RTS/CTS in kernel and in RS232 PCI-E board, etc.

So the question is, how i can do correct binary file transfer from command line using HW flow control? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a guy who says he has a solution for transferring binary data with minicom:
http://www.dannysung.com/wmain/linux/tips/sending-binary-files-via-minicom/

I don't understand why his little script is different from `cat file >/dev/ttySX` but maybe you can give it a try.

Comment: Surprisingly it work! I also really don't understand what is difference of suggested script from simple `cat`, but it work. But only work from `minicom`: don't work from command line. Looks like `minicom` has some secret magic from old epoch, when all software was better and more correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I made those sort of test (20 years ago) I used unix dd command. Find a similar one in your linux flavor.

Comment: Thanks, i try `dd`, but unfortunately it not work: it always transfer data regardless of `BUSY` wire state, and i not found any working options for HW flow control in `dd`. (So `dd` works like `cat`).